# Creating another column condition on dates in the index

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe where one of the indices is based on the date.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
                     Value
Date       Category 
1980-12-31   Cat     100
             Dog     150
             Bat     200
1981-12-31   Cat     100
             Dog     150
             Bat     200
1982-12-31   Cat     100
             Dog     150
             Bat     200
```

For reference, the date in the index is formatted as

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%Y') + MonthEnd(0)
```

Although the output looks different to what I expect - I would have thought it should have months done as mmm rather than as a number

What I want is to add another column say 'Value_2' which is conditional on the date value in the index.
So for instance, if it is between 1980 and 1981, I want a value of 0.1; if it is less than 1982, I want 0.2; if it is greater than 1982, I want to return 0.5.

I have tried using

```
Early = df.loc['Date'] <= '1980-12-31'
Mid =  df.loc['Date'] > '1980-12-31' & df.loc['Date'] <= '1981-12-31'
Late = df.loc['Date'] > '1981-12-31' & df.loc['Date'] <= '1982-12-31'
df['Value_2'] = np.where(Early, 0.1, np.where(Mid, 0.2, 0.5)
```

But it's telling me  that it is an 'Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: Date'

What am I doing wrong, please?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` is the name of your index level, not a position in the index itself. You can't do `df.loc['Date']`, I think you want `df[:'1980-12-31']` and so on. For example:

```
df[:'1980-12-31']
```

gives:

```
                     Value
Date       Category       
1980-12-31 Cat           0
           Dog           1
           Bat           2
```

In your case, `cut` would be a better choice:

```
df['Value_2'] = pd.cut(df.index.get_level_values('Date'), 
           pd.to_datetime(['1980-12-31','1981-12-31','1982-12-31', '2020-12-31']),
           include_lowest=True,
           labels=[0.1,0.2,0.5])
```

Output:

```
                     Value Value_2
Date       Category               
1980-12-31 Cat           0     0.1
           Dog           1     0.1
           Bat           2     0.1
1981-12-31 Cat           3     0.1
           Dog           4     0.1
           Bat           5     0.1
1982-12-31 Cat           6     0.2
           Dog           7     0.2
           Bat           8     0.2
```

Comment: Thanks very much. One follow up, please. There’s going to be quite a bit of complexity for the values I want in ‘Value_2’. So for instance, there will be other dates that are in between the dates I’m showing...eg 15 June 1981 would need to show as 0.2 in Value_2. Is there a way of incorporating this, please?

Comment: Aslo, you may want to pass `right=False` to `pd.cut`.

Comment: This is amazingly helpful. Thank you!